# Rashi script in certain seforim

Tags: jewish-books, writing-printing

I noticed that some authors of seforim have their books published using Rashi script instead of ashuris script. Was this done by default of the printers or was there some halachic reason not to use Ashuris script for their seforim. Just for example the Chasam Sofer is in Rashi script amongst many others. Anyone know the reason?

Comment: I think you will find many hassidic sefarim written in that typeset. The reason I've always heard was so as not to use ashuris. Seemingly a display of humility, as if their seffer wasn't worthy.

Comment: @DanF The script isn't Ashuris... That's the reason it's humble because Ashuris is reserved for main texts and works

Comment: @ezra OK. What's the source that "Ashurit" is considered "non humble"? I'm unfamiliar with that aspect.

Comment: I was told the typesetters preferred that script because it saved space (i.e. they could fit more text in the same space due to the compactness of the characters.

Comment: @Ploni Also the letters could be printed smaller than block letters with minimum ink splotches, based on the shape of the characters.

Comment: @sam - Your example of  Chasam Sofer is interesting, because the  Chasam Sofer would write a שטר הזמנה [summons] in כתב אשורית (see כתב סופר אה"ע סוף סי' כ"ב ).

Comment: There is a teshuva of the rema about not using כתב אשורית. R. H. Schachter is makpid for this reason to print his bechinos in Rashi script (however, his seforim are in block print)

Answer (score 4):

See Teshuvos Ha-Rema (R. Moshe Isserles), 34:

> ועיקר ספרים שלנו כתובים או נדפסים בכתב שאינו אשורי, והוא מטעם שאנו
>   כותבים תורה שבעל פה כמו שפסקו הפוסקים ואיתא בגמרא מטעם דעת לעשות
>   לה' הפרו תורתך, א"כ ה"ה בכתיבה זאת. ואפשר דהראשונים ז"ל המציאו כתב
>   אחר כדי לכתוב הדברים שבע"פ, ואע"פ שלא ניתנו לכתוב אפשר דהיינו בכתב
>   אשורי שהתורה שבכתב נכתב בה אבל בשאר כתבים אין לחוש

In short, the Rema suggests that perhaps the non-Ashuri script (i.e., Rashi script) was invented in order to alleviate the problem of writing down Torah Shebe'al Peh.

An earlier source is a teshuva of the Rambam (Pe'er Ha-Dor, 7) in which he also says that כתב אשורית should not be used for anything other than Scripture:

> ומן הראוי לך שתדע כי הכתיבה הזאת הנקראת כתב אשורית כיון שנתנה בו תורה
>   ובו נכתבו לוחות הברית כי הוא מגונה מאד להשתמש בו רק בכתבי הקדש ומימי
>   קדם ישראל נזהרין בזאת והיו כתביהן וחבורי חכמותיהם וכתבי חול שלהם בכתב
>   עברי לכן תמצא חרות על שקלי הקדש דברים של חול בכתב עברי ולא נמצא מעולם
>   אות אחת מזה הכתב אשורי' בדבר שנמצא משארית ישראל לא במטבע ולא באבן אלא
>   הכל בכתב עברי וע"כ שנו הספרדיי' כתיבתם ושמו אותותם אותות אחרות עד שנעשה הכתב ככתב אחר להתיר להשתמש בו בדברי חול

However, in Shulchan Aruch (Yoreh Deah 284:2), the Rema records this view as:

> וי"א דאין לכתוב **דברים של חול** בכתב אשורית

This would seem to imply that as long as the written matter is not something *chol*, i.e., devoid of religious value, it may be written in כתב אשורית. This *diyuk* is also made by R. Moshe Feinstein (Igros Moshe YD 3:120) who rules that a *kesubah* may be written in כתב אשורית because it is not devoid of religious value. R. Moshe adds that this is not a matter of strict halachah as the Rambam himself does not mention this in his code at all and R. Yosef Caro, who cites Rambam's teshuvah in the Beis Yosef, omits it from Shulchan Aruch as well:

> אבל נראה דכתובה כיון שהוא תיקון חכמים לכותבו אין זה בכלל דברי חול
>   שכתב הרמ"א. דאם היתה כוונתו דברי חול כל דבר שאינו מכתבי הקדש, הי"ל לכתוב חוץ מגט דגט נמי אינו מכתבי הקדש והוא ג"כ דבר חול ככל שטרות...  איברא שהרמב"ם בתשובתו שהוא מקור האיסור שהביאו ר' ירוחם בנתיב השני סוף חלק ב' משמע שאוסר בכל דברי חול אף של מצוה וחיוב דהא גם בגט שכתב שם ורבינו יהוסף הלוי מנע לכתוב הגט בכתיבה התלויה, שלכן חזרו הסופרים לכתוב הגט בכתיבה מיושרת בכתב אשורית וגם זה עכב על ידם ואמר להם ואיך נשתמש בזה בכתב אלקים ויבא לזלזול עיי"ש והובא גם בב"י אה"ע שם, מ"מ הרמ"א משמע שאינו פוסק כוותיה אלא בדברי חול ממש היינו שאין מצוה וחיוב לכותבו דלכן לא הוצרך לכתוב דהוא חוץ מגט. וגם הב"י ביו"ד ס"ס רפ"ג לא העתיק סוף התשובה בדבר הגט שג"כ אוסר הר"י מיגאש משמע שבזה אינו פוסק לא רק מצד שבגט איכא פוסלים כדפסק באה"ע דעכ"פ הי"ל להביא כדי לאסור כתובה שלכן משמע שלא פסק כמותו אלא בדברי חול ממש היינו שהם דברי רשות ולא כתובה שהוא מצוה וחיוב. וכיון שאין זה ענין איסור דהרי הרמב"ם עצמו לא הזכיר זה בחבורו והש"ע אף שהביא זה בב"י לא הזכיר זה בש"ע כלל לכן יש לסמוך למעשה להתיר

Answer (score 2):

Many years ago I saw [a copy of?] the first [dated] printed Sefer. It was the Rashi on the Torah.(It was published in Italy in 1475)  It was typeset in what we call Rashi Script. I postulate that that is the reason that we call that script “Rashi script.” I believe that Rashi did not use that script. Rather it was a Sefardic script that was purposefully used so as not to use the Torah (Ashuris) script, which has Kedushah.

The “Rashi script” has many letters which are passul if used for the Torah. In Halacha, Hilchos Sefer Torah, Yoreh Deah, it is called “כתב מאשיט״” which could be translated something like “the Sloppy script.” The idea is the same, to limit the use of the holy Ashuris script.

I learned hilchos Sta”m when I was in Yeshiva, and I occasionally prepared invitations for friends when they were getting married. I remember learning (from someone) that Rav Schwab (IIRC) was not pleased with invitations that were made in regular ksav Ashuris, because of that Halacha in Yoreh Deah. He preferred that invitations should be written in ksav mashit, or any other non-halachic script because the invitations would be discarded and it would be better not to use the Ashuris script which has so much kedusha!